# String -> date, date -> calendar, calendar subtract day, calendar -> data -> String

Tags: calendar, simpledateformat

Нужно реализовать такой алгоритм.
String -> date, date -> calendar, calendar subtract day, calendar -> data -> String

Например, пользователь ввел даты FROM = 03.07.2017 и TO = 04.07.2017.
а программа дала два результата за 03.07.2017 и 04.07.2017 и за
FROM = 02.07.2017 и TO = 03.07.2017.

Загвоздка - дату FROM и TO я извлекаю из assemblyParameters в виде строки.
Мне нужно парсить ее в SimpleDateFormat, отнимать один день, сново парсить в строку и передавать обратно в assemblyParameters.

У меня трудность в моменте "сново парсить в строку". Я использовал new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(docDateTo2);

```
 private String dateEditing() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    format.applyPattern("dd.mm.yyyy");
    String sql = null;
    String dataFrom = assemblyParameters.getFrom();
    String dataTo = assemblyParameters.getTo();
    try {
        Date docDateFrom= format.parse(dataFrom);
        cal.setTime(docDateFrom);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        Date docDateFrom2 = cal.getTime();
        String dataFrom2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy").format(docDateFrom2);
        assemblyParameters.setFrom(dataFrom2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Date docDateTo= format.parse(dataTo);
        cal.setTime(docDateTo);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        Date docDateTo2 = cal.getTime();
        String dataTo2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy").format(docDateTo2);
        assemblyParameters.setFrom(dataTo2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sql = assemblyParameters.getInfo().get("query_full");
    return sql;
}
```

так не работает =(